# ValueError message on a DataLoader object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with some tensor flow codes and I am getting ValueError.

Here is the code

```
# Model training
with torch.no_grad():
    for _ in range(10):
        for samples, labels in tqdm(train_dl, desc="Iteration {}".format(_ + 1)):
            samples = samples.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

           samples_hv = model.encode(samples)
           model.model_update(samples_hv, labels)
```

and here is the error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-8d8911e340c1> in <module>()
      2 with torch.no_grad():
      3     for _ in range(10):
----> 4         for samples, labels in tqdm(train_dl, desc="Iteration {}".format(_ + 1)):
      5             samples = samples.to(device)
      6             labels = labels.to(device)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Please I need some help.

Take note the **train_dl** is a DataLoader object

The **train_dl** was gotten from the following codes:

```
# Split the dataset into 80% training and 30% testing
train_size = int(len(ds) * 0.8)
test_size = len(ds) - train_size
train_ds, test_ds = data.random_split(ds, [train_size, test_size])

train_dl = data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
test_dl = data.DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Please add more information about `train_dl`, how you created it, or the `__getitem__` method

Comment: Your `train_dl` is not returning a tuple but a single value.

Comment: # Split the dataset into 80% training and 30% testing
train_size = int(len(ds) * 0.8)
test_size = len(ds) - train_size
train_ds, test_ds = data.random_split(ds, [train_size, test_size])

train_dl = data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
test_dl = data.DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=1)

Comment: As @MichelKok said, `train_dl` is returning a single value but in your code you expect 2. The returned value depend on your dataset and how it is built, please see [the doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)